# Building an app for PC and Android questions

Tags: java, c#, android

So I am looking into building an application that would be for PC and Android devices. Of course they would have different UI but I am trying to figure out where to start with them both using the same back end.

So it would be a quiz game lets say. They would have similar but difference interfaces but they would using the similar backend logic. Anyone have good references to start with. I don't want to end up doing more then I need to. Also trying to figure out what I want to work in. Seems like I would have to use Java and Oracle, but I much rather use C# and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good answer to your question. If I were you, a would create a separated business logic and serve it via Webservices. All UI can implement that interface. By the way there some compact solutions for UI what can run on PC (browser) and on Android (browser or native). What technology you use, depends on the needs and your opinion. If you have big data, you should not use SQL for example. Most of us developing under "Java" on android, so there are many material in that topic. On the server side, you have infinity choice. ;)